# I deleted my Downloads folder, why can't I remove the items pinned to my sidebar?

Tags: finder, sidebar

I moved my download folder on to an external hard drive and then deleted the folder on my Mac.

I clearly had folders I had pinned to the side bar with a root folder in the download folder I deleted.

As a result, when I click on one of those items in the sidebar, it does not respond.

All I am able to do is ctrl click which gives me the option to open sidebar preferences.

How can I unpin these from my sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold command and click and drag the alias out if the side to remove, I believe.